# How to resolve InvalidAuthenticityToken on Rails Stripe App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, stripe-payments, fetch-api

Hi I am implementing a checkout in my Rails 5 app using Stripe.  The checkout process will allow the user to checkout using Apple Pay or Google Pay.  I have used the example JS code from the Stripe docs to implement the Payment Request. I am also adding the X-CSRF-Token to the headers in the xhr post request to the server:

```
...
fetch('/checkout', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({token: ev.token.id}),
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
})
...
```

In the response from the server I am receiving:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in CheckoutController#create
```

I am using Devise to protect the checkout and I have read that you can disable the authenticity checks by adding this in the controller:

```
protect_from_forgery prepend: true
```

However this results in 302 redirect to /users/sign_in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your request is not authenticated, because it is sent without cookies, since `Fetch API`'s `fetch` does not include cookies by default.

Set `credentials` option to include cookies in request.

```
fetch('/checkout', {
  // ...
  credentials: 'same-origin'  // or 'include' (see the link below)
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included